# Error creating MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I get an error when running the following create table:

```
CREATE TABLE Event (
    id      VARCHAR(10)         NOT NULL,
    title       VARCHAR(100),
    start_date  DATE            NOT NULL,
    end_date    DATE,
    description TEXT,
    url     VARCHAR(200),
    website     VARCHAR(200),
    location    VARCHAR(32)     NOT NULL;
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (location) REFERENCES Location(id)
);
```

The error I get is this:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 9
```

I know that this error has to do with incompatibility with the syntax and the mysql version running, but I've checked every line and the syntax is correct according to the documentation. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for all your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the semicolon on line:

```
 location    VARCHAR(32)             NOT NULL;
```

to a comma.

Comment: Damn, now I feel like a complete noob. How was I missing that out? Thanks :)

Comment: Usually happens to me when I've been staring at the screen for too long. Do you have any trees you can stare at for 5 minutes? :)

Comment: Well, it's night over here in Portugal, so I'll just stare at the moon :)